# Incremental searching with the `less` utility

Tags: linux, command-line, less

Does `less` have an incremental search?

I'm on xubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately the `less` pager does not have this functionality. The only search options available are `/` for a forward search, and `?` for a backward search.

Comment: someone should implement that ability then ;)

Comment: according to the manpage: "n .. repeat previous search" ... isnt that incremental?

Comment: Incremental usually means "search as you type". See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/10/search-if-it-isnt-incremental-its-excremental.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use `view` (`vim` in read only mode) as a replacement for less.. vim has incremental search, just add:

```
set incsearch
```

to your .vimrc

Comment: I know about it but can you pipe text to it? i.e. use it as a pager for other tools (such as `git`)

Comment: looks like vim comes with a script for that.. export PAGER=/usr/share/vim/vim71/macros/less.sh or if you google 'vimpager' there is a supposedly better replacement..  git sort of has issues with it because of the terminal escape codes for color, but there might be an easy fix for that...

Comment: I forgot about view

Answer (score 1):

I added incremental search to less and pushed it to [a fork on GitHub](https://github.com/matthewlmcclure/less/commits/master).